# Input from mvc application is not getting submitted in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a simple MVC application. It has a view called Index in the folder home, in the view i have some input boxes, wich inputs i wish to save as a object and save in a database. i have create the view from a controller that i have created. My problem is when i click the button for submit nothing seems to happen? 

Here is the code i have in the view.

```
    @model FlexMVC.FlexBookingDb.Resevation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Resevation</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResevationDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResevationDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResevationDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ResevationTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResevationTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ResevationTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Car, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Car, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Car, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartLocation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartLocation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndLocation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndLocation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And here is my controller code.

```
namespace FlexMVC.Controllers
{
    public class ResevationController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Resevation
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Resevation
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Resevation resevation)
        {
            ResevationModels model = new ResevationModels();

            resevation.Car = 1;
            resevation.Customer = 1;

            model.CreateResevation(resevation);

            return View(model);
        }

    }
}
```

can anybody explain to me what i am doing wrong? and please say if i should post the model code as well.

Edit:
Here is the code for the CreateResevation Method.

```
public void CreateResevation(Resevation resevation)
    {
        resevation.Car = FindAvaliableCar(resevation.ResevationDate, resevation.ResevationTime);

        _db.Resevations.InsertOnSubmit(resevation);
        _db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Which action returns the view you're showing us?  Which action is invoked by the form submit?  The form itself isn't specifying which view to use.  If `Index` is returning the form, then you may be submitting back to `Index` which doesn't do anything.

Comment: @David i am new to MVC so i am not sure about this. But i want the action Create to be fired when the submit button i clicked. and i dosent really matter wich view i returned after the button is clicked i just wish to insert the data for now? if that makes sense.

Comment: You can specify which action to invoke when you call `Html.BeginForm()`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx

Comment: Please post the code to `model.CreateResevation(resevation);` I assume this is the part you are expecting it to save to the database in.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint to your post method, does it get hit?

Comment: Hey webnoob, no i ist not hitting the breakpoint so the action dosent seem to be fired? i have posted the code for the method above for you.

Comment: In that case, check out @orel answer and specify the action against the `BeginForm` to make sure it posts back correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1. You probably submitting to the wrong action. You're submitting to *Index* while you probably meant to submit *Create*. This can be fixed by changing to `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerNameHere"))`
2. The *AntiForgeryToken* needs a `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]` validation attribute on the proposed Action.

Change it to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Create(Resevation resevation)
```

Comment: FYI: `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` is not required. The only way it would be required is if the controller specified it and the view didn't.

Comment: OrelEraki Thanks for the answer. I am a little confused about this part of MVC. So my controller class is called ResevationController and the action is called create. @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ResevationController")) is this the right way to write it then? i am getting an error saying the resources is not found when i try this?

Comment: @KevinJensen, Don't mention the suffix Controller inside `BegindForm`

Comment: @OrelEraki okay, so i should do like this ? (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home")) ? it still dont seem to work when i do it like this

Comment: @KevinJensen, Still ?

Comment: @OrelEraki yes it is still not working, i don't know what it could be then?

Comment: @OrelEraki Could the problem be in the route config?

Comment: @KevinJensen, Put a breakpoint on the first row inside `Create` action, and tell us if you hit it.

Comment: No i am not hitting the break point. and this is when i wrtie it like this: using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))

Comment: Could you download and use Fiddler Web Debugging and see if a request is indeed fired through your browser ?

Comment: @OrelEraki i will try that and se if i can see any thing

Comment: @OrelEraki it looks like it is fired through my browser, there is a 404 with a !.

Comment: @KevinJensen, You should fire it to `Resevation` controller, which means `Html.BeginForm("Create", "Resevation")`

Comment: @OrelEraki Thank you ! now it works, you are a life saver.

Comment: @KevinJensen, No problem, also try to take the time to read about Controllers. Also feel free to Upvote the answer :)

Comment: @OrelEraki Yes i think i have to read up on all of the controller part and how routing works! :) i have upvoted it and maked it as answered :)